# ASP.NET MVC HtmlTagBuilder dosen't work

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I tried to extend the HtmlHelper by a paragraph element this is the Code:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Para(ByRef helper As HtmlHelper) As String
    Dim builder = New TagBuilder("p")
    builder.SetInnerText("Hello World")
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

View:

```
@ModelType BookViewModel
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

@Using (Ajax.Form("Index", "BooksController", "BookList", "ajax_form"))
     @<input type = "search" name="search" id="search" />
    @<input type = "submit" value="Filter" />
End Using

    @Html.Para()
    @Html.Partial("_Books", Model)
```

It produces the following Output on the page:

```
<p> Hello World </p>
```

instead of only Hello World.

Why isn't this working.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to call this function on your page.

Comment: try to return an MvcHtmlString object instead of just a simple String

Comment: Works fine, thank you @ADyson